# IE: Unable to download FILENAME from SITENAME. Unable to open this internet site

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, download

After a futile day of searching related sites for kernels of information, I have decided it's time to ask the experts at Stack Overflow.  We have a classic ASP site which we use to feed reports to users over https.  It's been running well for years.  We recently added an extremely large report (250 MB zipped) which breaks the software when the user tries to download the report.  We get the "Open/Save/Cancel" dialog box OK, but clicking "Open" fails and clicking "Save" serves up the error message in the title.  Smaller files work OK.  We are able to duplicate this problem in a variety of IE versions in our test area using the same dataset.

The technology to download the report is circa 1990.  We have a VB6 DLL which is called from inside the ASP code with the address of the desired file.  The DLL opens the file and fills an array of bytes with the bytes of the zip file, and passes it back to the ASP page which streams out the array of bytes in a "Response.BinaryWrite" call.  Like I say, this works well with smaller files and appears to work with even bigger files than the one in question (at least we have not heard complaints from the users).  I would say there's something wrong with the file except that we can duplicate the error in a variety of environments.

My teammates and I have tried the easy solutions provided in the Google searches we have done, without any change in the result ('Response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", " no-store, no-cache " ', modifying the registry, etc).  I'm hoping somebody has encountered this problem before and can offer up some new ideas.  If you require more information please ask and we'll do our best to answer.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Mike

Comment: It sounds like a problem with downloading huge files. What server are you on? Did you check your weblog to see if there's an http error? I presume you have response.buffer set to false and are streaming directly to the client? If not, it could be that your response buffer is exceeded and you might need to increase aspbufferinglimit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, AardVark71, we increased the aspbufferinglimit on the server as you suggest and it's  working now.  We also bumped the script timeout variables on both the server and the page to ensure the page has enough time to complete the task.